# how to download certificate from Azure keyvault in .cer format using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I would like to download certificate from keyvault in the format .cer as part of my automation script. How would I do it using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download the certificate as `.cer` file in the automation runbook, you could use the script below to download it to the temp folder `$env:temp`.

Make sure you have already added the service principal related to the RunAs Account to the `Access policies` of your keyvault, it needs the `Get` in *Secret Permissions* and `Get` in *Certificate Permissions*.

[image]

**Sample:**

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$cert = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "joykeyvault" -Name "test1234"
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "joykeyvault" -Name $cert.Name

$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText)
$x509Cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$x509Cert.Import($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")

$cer = Export-Certificate -Cert $x509Cert -FilePath $env:temp\test.cer
Write-Output $cer
```

[image]

Comment: the current version of Powershell AZ doesn't output the secret via the SecretValueText property anymore.  See here for alternatives: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14233

Comment: this might help: https://dev.to/swimburger/convertfrom-securestring-a-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-matches-parameter-name-asplaintext-l4o